# Slow down a particle system on a path?

Tags: animation, particles

Hey there I have particles following a path.

I want them to follow the path at a constant speed until they are about 90% along the path, and then I want their speed along the path to slow down to a stop at the end of the path.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried this https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-slow-a-particle-system-down-2-8/1152711/7 but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explaint more about your settings, add some screenshots too. the lifetime option works for that, but maybe with more info someone could suggest a different option

Comment: you misunderstood what the guy explained in the link. The average/abolute speed will slow down, not just at the end. You can try to reach the effect with force fields.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it you want to slow down the already born and moving particles. The method described in your link (with changing the lifetime) only slows down the particles born from the moment of lifetime change on.

To make it work in the way you want it, you need another force field, as @Chris suggested, like *Drag* for example. The problem is, if you're using the *Curve Guide* force field where the speed is controlled by the particles' lifetime, *Drag* will have no effect.

In order to make it work you need to set the force field on the curve to *Force* with a negative strength to attract particles, and choose *Shape* > *Curve*. The result will behave a little different than the *Curive Guide* force field, maybe you have to play around with it to get the desired movement.

But this way you can place a *Drag* force field somewhere on the curve with a *Max Distance* setting enabled to limit its influence on the particles.

[image: force field curve]